# SharpPcap OnPcapStatistics event raises exception when using filters?

Tags: c#, .net, winpcap, sharppcap

duo to

> [SharpPcap OnPcapStatistics event never fires?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458542/sharppcap-onpcapstatistics-event-never-fires)

I have fixed it by placing override for PcapDevice.SendPacketArrivalEvent() and virtual for WinPcapDevice.SendPacketArrivalEvent() and it works perfect , but when i add some filters like this :

> device.Filter = "ip and tcp";

it raises exception that the drive is not ready, why is it like this?

Comment: If you're going to hack a library that you aren't familiar with then you should probably make sure you have the debugging skills to figure out what you broke.

Comment: Hi. As mentioned in the other issue the statistics issue has been resolved in that test release and in git master. Can you include the exception information that you get when you set that filter and some more source code showing how you are doing things? Have you looked at the filter examples in the sharppcap source release?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I have been putting the filter line before opening the device. know it works fine.

Comment: You should probably answer your own question just so the question shows up as closed :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my mistake, I have been putting the filter line before opening the device. know it works fine.